# NetSuite - System_Notes SQL to obtain STATUS as of a past date using SYSTEM_NOTES

Tags: mysql

Everything I've seen on the subject of NetSuite SYSTEM_NOTES discusses mostly saved searches or PHP. I've been trying to write a sql-based query that will join in SYSTEM_NOTES so that I can see what a status was on a particular past date for a particular table.

So for example, here is what I have so far. I think I must go through one or more levels to get down to SYSTEM_NOTES but I cannot seem to find the link. The schema does not show any info for SYSTEM_NOTES.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

--get count of all JOBS that were backlogged as of 01/01/2015

```
SELECT  A.CUSTOMER_ID, A.STATUS 
      FROM CUSTOMERS A 
        JOIN SYSTEM_NOTES C ON ????
        WHERE C.DATE = (SELECT MAX(C1.DATE) FROM SYSTEM_NOTES C1
                       WHERE C1.? = C.?
                       AND C1.DATE <= '2015-01-01')
        where A.CATEGORY_0 = 'JOB'
        AND C.STANDARD_FIELD = 'STATUS'
        and C.VALUE_NEW = 'Not Started'
        and A.DUE_DATE < '2015-01-01'
```